# Is there a way we can select and clear points in plotly python dashboard?

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

I wanted to select the points in a graph and delete them permanently that is present inside the box selection or lasso selection.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a callback that takes your `dcc.Graph` component's [`selectedData`](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/graph#graph-properties) property as an `Input` and do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Patch
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input, State
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate

df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "y": [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]})

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = dcc.Graph(id="graph", figure=go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=df["x"], y=df["y"])))


@app.callback(
    Output("graph", "figure"),
    Input("graph", "selectedData"),
    State("graph", "figure"),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def on_selection(selected_data, figure):
    selected_points = figure["data"][0].get("selectedpoints")

    if not selected_points:
        raise PreventUpdate

    dff = df[df["x"].isin(selected_points)]

    return go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=dff["x"], y=dff["y"]))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

The code above assumes the figure has a single trace.

I'm getting the selected points' x values from the figure itself here because it's less code/work in comparison to extracting the values from the `selectedData` property value.